# how can we handle the action of uicollectionview?

Tags: ipad, ios7, uicollectionview

i have 5 button in collection view .each button have brand logo like nike reebok etc.and it has one IBAction i.e. buttonpressed.
i have one array that contain key and value like

```
(
   {
      id=1
      brandname=nike
   },

  {
     id=2
    brandname=reebok
  },

 .
 .
 .
 .

)
```

when i clicked on nike button of collection view its call the buttonpressed ibaction and store the data in array only the brandname is " nike "

second thing is when i cliked on that nike button first time after that this button stayed remain as pressed and not click on twice

hows it is possible to match the condition in IBAction method .....

please tell me i am the new buddy in ios.

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv 
        cellForItemAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
           UICollectionViewCell *cell=[cv 
           dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" 
           forIndexPath:indexPath];




    collectionView_button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    collectionView_button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 98, 48) ];

    collectionView_button.tag = indexPath.item;

        NSString *imageNames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr_ButtonImg
       objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

        [collectionView_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageNames] 
         forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [collectionView_button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell addSubview:collectionView_button];

    }
```

//ibaction

```
    -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
    {

    int c=0;

    for (int i=0; i<[Temp_arr_JsonData count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *str_brandname = [[Temp_arr_JsonData objectAtIndex: i] 
         valueForKey:@"storebrand"];

        NSLog(@"%@",str_brandname);

        NSObject *myNewObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];

        if ([str_brandname isEqualToString:@"Nike"])
        {
            NSLog(@"Data matched");
            c++;
            myNewObject=[Temp_arr_JsonData objectAtIndex:i];
            [temparray addObject:myNewObject];
        }
    }

    arr_JsonData=temparray;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [sender setSelected:YES];

    }
```

When I click on Reebok button its display both Nike and Reebok data in table ... I want only the condition that are in ibaction

Comment: when i click on reebok button its display both nike and reebok data in table ... i want only the condition that are in ibaction

Comment: no one is eligible for my question ?